# Get the label of edited column in lwc datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, onchange

I have a datatable with 10 columns  -
ex -

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import generateData from './generateData';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' ,editable=true},
    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url' , editable=true},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' ,editable=true},
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        const data = generateData({ amountOfRecords: 100 });
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

If i edit  the phone number or Name or website , I need the label of the column.
If i change the phone from 234 to 567 on the datatable UI - In the js i need which field i have edited.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the datatable editable, I suggest the following markup:

```html
<lightning-datatable
    editable="true"
    key-field="id"
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    onsave={handleSave}
>
```

In Javascript, the following finds the label:

```javascript
handleSave(event) {
    event.detail.draftValues.forEach(row => {
        for(const fieldName in row) {
            if(fieldName !== 'id') {
                const label = columns.find(col => col.fieldName === fieldName).label;
                console.log(label);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As can be seen, retrieving the fieldName comes first. Retrieving the label requires (to my knowledge) a lookup in the table definition.